# what is the blocks that i need to make memory 16*16 bit slot in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

my problem is i need the blocks that i will use them to make memory slot in VHDL.
I want this name of this blocks to write the structure code of the blocks and connect them with each other to make the memory slot.
and thank you.

Comment: This question is not clear to me.  Can you expand on exactly what you want to do and where you are stuck?

Comment: i want to know the blocks that i connect them together to make memory slot in VHDL

Answer (score 0):

For simple memories you can just infer them with portable VHDL. This allows your code to run on multiple device families and across manufacturers. You may have to instantiate a library component to get more advanced features but most synthesizers can infer the most common forms of memory. The details are in your vendor's documentation.

The example will work in most tools to generate a synchronous RAM:

```
library ieee; use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ram is
  port (
    Clock   : in std_logic;
    Address : in unsigned;
    We      : in std_logic;
    Wr_data : in bit_vector;
    Rd_Data : out bit_vector
  );
end entity;

architecture simple of ram is
  constant MEM_SIZE : positive := 2 ** Address'length;
  type ram_mem is array (0 to MEM_SIZE-1) of bit_vector(Wr_data'length-1 downto 0);

  signal ram_data : ram_mem;
begin

  rd_wr: process(Clock)
  begin
    if rising_edge(Clock) then
      Rd_data <= ram_data(to_integer(Address));

      if We = '1' then
        ram_data(to_integer(Address)) <= Wr_data;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

end architecture;
```

The address and data ports are unconstrained with widths determined at instantiation. You can get a 16x16-bit memory by connecting a 4-bit `Address` and 16-bit `Wr_data` and `Rd_data` signals.

Comment: please, What about the Top Level Diagram ?!!

Comment: This IS the top level VHDL file. You don't need any sub-components for such a simple task.